# How can I install basemap in a python virtual environment on mac?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, geos

I'm trying to install basemap to plot lat/long data. I'm following the instructions [at this website](
http://gnperdue.github.io/yak-shaving/osx/python/matplotlib/2014/05/01/basemap-toolkit.html) because they seemed the simplest of all those that I found.

However, I'm getting stuck at the last step, which is to run in Terminal

```
basemap-1.1.0$ python setup.py install
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
error: Command "gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/gitanjali/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/gitanjali/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/geos/include -I['/Users/gitanjali/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'] -I/Users/gitanjali/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/gitanjali/miniconda3/include/python3.7m -c src/_geoslib.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src/_geoslib.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/src/_geoslib.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

I'm also told that "101 warnings and 15 errors generated".

Despite this dire set of warnings, when I go to examples and run python simpletest.py, there's no problem -- I get a map.

Though I get a map when running commands in Terminal, I'm unable to access basemap as a module in regular python files. That is, when I try to run a file with "import basemap", I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basemap'
```

I'm at a loss as to what's going wrong. If anyone could help me troubleshoot, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "Though I get a map when running commands in Terminal, I'm unable to access basemap as a module in regular python files." - What's the difference then? Running `python somefile.py` is the same as typing `python` and then writing the content in the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, But the problem isn't at venv, is at your python's version, as basemap seems don't work with newer version of python.